# Fetching field from JSON API data

Tags: c#

How can I fetch a specific field from a JSON text?
I am developing an online ticket shop, and in the sign up form the user has to fill a country combobox. I am filling that combobox dynamically using a RESTful API: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all. I need to fetch only the name field and add it to my combobox. How can I do that?

My code so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Country> countries = GetCountryNames();
            foreach(Country country in countries)
            {
                country_dropdown_list.Items.Add(country.getCountryName());
            }
        }

        //Calls API to fill combobox with country names
        protected List<Country> GetCountryNames() 
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = 
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"));
            request.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Server);

            string jsonString;
            using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                List<String> countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(jsonString);
            }

            return countries;
        }
```

I am using a custom class for deserealization, but I think I could manage it just with a String List, I think.

Comment: Why are you using HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient? In .NET Core HttpWebRequest is just a legacy facade over HttpClient. Besides, JSON is just text as far as HTTP is concerned. You can't retrieve a specific field, you need to retrieve the entire response. Unless the API allows retrieving specific fields only, you'll have to retrieve and parse the entire response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation page of the API you use shows [how to filter the response](https://restcountries.eu/#filter-response) and retrieve the fields you want, eg :

```
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;capital;currencies
```

As far as HTTP is concerned, JSON is just text. There's no way to tell a service to return specific fields unless the service itself provides a way to do that. Otherwise you have to retrieve the entire response and parse it.

Finally, HttpWebRequest is a legacy class and shouldn't be used when HttpClient is available. In .NET Core HttpWebRequest is a legacy facade over HttpClient.

In .NET 5 you could replace all your code with a single call to HttpClient and [GetFromJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_Json_HttpClientJsonExtensions_GetFromJsonAsync__1_System_Net_Http_HttpClient_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

```
record Country(string Name);
...
var url="https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name";

var countries=await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Country>(url);
```

In general, most public APIs have a way of reducing their output - or charge you for it. All hosters and cloud providers charge for outbound traffic. Unless the site has a way to filter its output it will end up paying for your requests.

Comment: Completely missed that part in the documentation thanks! It works now perfectly